# How to set data-theme in asp.net MVC dropdownlistfor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

Using the standard themes, my page is "C", but instead of a white dropdown, i'd like to have a blue dropdown from theme "B".  Is there a way to set the data-theme when using the `DropdownListFor` shortcut?

i.e.  something like:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SomeId, new SelectList(Model.SomeList, "Id", "Name"), 
new { id = "SomeSelectedId",  name = "xxx", onchange = "this.form.submit();", **DATA-THEME="B"** })
```

Tried a number of things unsuccessfully, any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to switch to a RouteValueDictionary:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SomeId, new SelectList(Model.SomeList, "Id", "Name"), 
    new RouteValueDictionary(new { id = "SomeSelectedId",  name = "xxx", onchange = "this.form.submit();"})
        {{"data-theme", "B"}})
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response.  I spent way too much time going down dead-ends.